# Place widgets on top of each other

Tags: android, layout

I have a camera widget which would be a "background", on top of it I would like to have an image and a button. What layout should I use to correctly place image and button on top of camera widget?

The following layout pushes camera widget off the screen (just image and button are visible):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <eu.livotov.labs.android.camview.CAMView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/zxScanCamera"/>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/hud"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        style="@style/StdText"
        android:id="@+id/flashLight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/scan_flash_on"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `FrameLayout` is the correct choice. Try setting the background of the ImageView to transparent `android:backgroud="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: Thanks, transparent background did not work but I've played a bit with options and setting `android:background="@drawable/hud"` + `android:layout_gravity="center"` did solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) - it uses the order of definition of its children for their Z-order (on top of each other). Firs declare your `CAMView` and then (as siblings in the resource file) - the button and the image view. Of course you should consider their relative position on the screen (inside their parent), but in short - each next child is drawn "on top" of the previous if they overlap in `x,y` coordinates.

In your case:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <eu.livotov.labs.android.camview.CAMView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        .../>

    <ImageView
        ...
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <Button
        ...
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use the `android:layout_alignParent...` properties to place your items inside their parent

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to give alignment to any of the child views eg button should be on top and in middle then its better to go for RelativeLayout

Answer (score -2):

If you use a constraint layout, the widgets that are below in the list will appear above all the others in the app.[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWwgy.png) For example in this, theimageView1 will appear on the top of imageView2. (From above or top, I mean towards the user OR towards out of the screen. imageView1 will appear above imageView2 like you place a piece of paper on a big paper)

[image]